# Working with CDF Deployment

Tags: functions, sql, enterprise-cdf

I've been working with FreeCDFs in *Mathematica 10* and it has been going fine as long as I do not pull from a database or access local files. I recently purchased the *Mathematica 10.2 Enterprise Edition* because I was under the impression that I would be able to create CDFs that would access MySQL. When I try to create my CDFs and embed them into my HTML code when I open up the browser I see the manipulate window but where I should see a table of computed data I just see the definition of my function and variables the manipulation should be running through. How can I get my CDFs to pull MySQL data and run it through my function?

Answer (score 4):

I contacted wolfram and what I needed to do was make sure that all my code was within the *Manipulate* and after defining my changing variables the rest of my code lies within a *Initialization* command. You also must have the Enterprise edition to make CDFs with *DatabaseLink*.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The free CDF player can not import data. That can only be done by the CDF player pro. Did you try to use SaveDefinitions->True within Manipulate?
That should store the needed data for Manipulate inside the CDF.

Comment: I have tried that but it crashes _Mathematica_ because of the amount of data it would need to store. Would anyone trying to access my embedded CDF have to have CDF Player Pro to use my interactive function? @Elsibär

Comment: On a [Wolfram Blog posting](http://blog.wolfram.com/2013/03/11/using-mathematica-enterprise-edition-to-create-professional-apps-tools-and-reports/) it says "Enterprise Edition allows you to create EnterpriseCDF files, which provide enhanced capabilities that can be deployed via the free Wolfram CDF Player.". So I presume that Enterprise Edition produces a type of CDF that makes the free CDF Player behave as if it is CDF Player Pro.